# Why do "large" arrays not implement std::fmt::Debug?

Tags: rust

I can print in `Debug` the following array:

```
fn main() {
    let array = [0; 5];
    println!("{:?}", array);
}
```

However, if the size is bigger, let's say it's 50, the trait `std::fmt::Debug` will not be implemented by default:

```
fn main() {
    let array = [0; 50];
    println!("{:?}", array);
}
```

Compilation error:

> error[E0277]: the trait bound `[{integer}; 50]: std::fmt::Debug` is not satisfied

Why is the `std::fmt::Debug` trait not implemented for some sizes of arrays?

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can use `&[T]` instead, since it is length-independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html:

> Arrays of sizes from 0 to 32 (inclusive) implement the following
>   traits if the element type allows it:
>
> - Clone (only if T: Copy)
> - Debug
> - IntoIterator (implemented for &[T; N] and &mut [T; N])
> - PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord
> - Hash
> - AsRef, AsMut
> - Borrow, BorrowMut
> - Default
>
> This limitation on the size
>   N exists because Rust does not yet support code that is generic over
>   the size of an array type. [Foo; 3] and [Bar; 3] are instances of same
>   generic type [T; 3], but [Foo; 3] and [Foo; 5] are entirely different
>   types. As a stopgap, trait implementations are statically generated up
>   to size 32.
>
> Arrays of any size are Copy if the element type is Copy. This works
>   because the Copy trait is specially known to the compiler.

Comment: I hope that 2017 will be the year were Rust gains integral generic parameters (I'd really like if it got MORE than just integrals, but integrals would be so helpful already).

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44580 for the tracking issue. It's getting closer.

Comment: There's also talk of having generic array implementations sooner, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/60466

Comment: One more year has passed.

Comment: With current rust version, the definition has changed  to "Arrays of any size implement the following traits if the element type allows it:

    Debug,
    IntoIterator (implemented for &[T; N] and &mut [T; N]),
    PartialEq, PartialOrd, Eq, Ord,
    Hash,
    AsRef, AsMut,
    Borrow, BorrowMut",

Only the Default trait is still limited to 32 element arrays.